I flagged an answer as a comment and the generated flagging-comment was transferred in error to another answer?
During review I encountered an answer that began "This is meant to be a comment ..." so I flagged it.
https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/74601
The answer I flagged was subsequently transferred by a moderator into a comment on another (good) answer. All good.
Unfortunately the comment created by my flag also got transferred across to the other (good) answer - to which it definitely does not apply.
I suspect a bug or a slip-up - should I just delete the misplaced comment? (if its a bug I probably should wait?)

There's no real bug here; this is a minor slip-up by the ♦ moderator; when they convert an answer into a comment, they have the option to migrate the comments as well.

You can save them a bit of work by deleting the comment yourself.

Thanks, will do
